# How to add cheat sheets menu item in help using commands

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have added Cheat Sheet menu item in Help menu using actions. For that am getting deprecated warnings for actions and actions Set. This is my previous code.

```
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
   <actionSet
        label="Cheat Sheets"
        visible="true"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actionSet">
    <action
        label="Cheat Sheets" 
        class=" org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.CheatSheetExtensionFactory:helpMenuAction"
        menubarPath="help/group.tutorials"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actions.CheatSheetHelpMenuAction">
    </action>
    </actionSet>
```

To remove warnings i decided to add through the commands. Here is my code

```
<extension 
point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
<menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:help?after=Dynamic Help">
     <command
           commandId="org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actions.CheatSheetHelpMenuAction"
           label="Cheat Sheets.."
           style="push">
     </command>
</menuContribution>
```

And i have added respective command

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command
        defaultHandler="org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.CheatSheetExtensionFactory:helpMenuAction"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actions.CheatSheetHelpMenuAction"
        name="Cheat sheets">
  </command>
```

But i am getting following error **org.eclipse.ui.internal.cheatsheets.actions.CheatSheetHelpMenuAction cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.commands.IHandler.** 
How can i fix this? i dont want to create new handler for this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fix the cast because an Action isn't suitable for a command handler. There doesn't seem to be an existing command handler for cheats sheets so there is nothing you could change this to.

Writing your own handler is also not possible as all the cheat sheet APIs are **internal** so they can't be used.

Although action sets are marked as deprecated they aren't ever going to be deleted because too many things use them - so stick to the action set.